# Remove Column name in a dictionary generated via Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in Pandas with two columns 'page_id' and 'access_time'. Each page_id could have multiple access_time values
Using the following code:

```
df.groupby('page_id').apply(lambda dfg: dfg.drop('page_id', 
axis=1).to_dict(orient='list')).to_dict()
```

I got the output as a nested dictionary:

```
{id1: {'access_time':[time1,time2]},id2:{'access_time':[time3]}}
```

What I want is a dictionary of lists as follows:

```
{id1:[time1,time2],id2:[time3]...}
```

How can I do that ?

And example of the Data is:

```
      page_id     accessed_time(string)
0     01          20171223
1     01          20171224
2     02          20171226
3     03          20171227
```

Comment: Can you give a short example of your DataFrame df?

Comment: just added an example of the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without looking into the logic of your code. The following can produce your desired output:

```
result = (
    df.groupby('page_id')
    .apply(lambda dfg: dfg.drop('page_id', axis=1).to_dict(orient='list'))
    .apply(lambda x: x['accessed_time'])
    .to_dict()
    )

result
Out[63]: {1: [20171223, 20171224], 2: [20171226], 3: [20171227]}
```

It seems it can be simplified to:

```
df.groupby('page_id').apply(lambda x: x.accessed_time.tolist()).to_dict()
{1: [20171223, 20171224], 2: [20171226], 3: [20171227]}
```

Or:

```
df.groupby('page_id').accessed_time.apply(list).to_dict()
Out[65]: {1: [20171223, 20171224], 2: [20171226], 3: [20171227]}
```

Comment: Thanks, close !! It produced a dictionary of nested list, which is a bit different from what I wanted 
{id1:[[time1,time2]],id2:[[time3]]...}

Comment: Oh, sorry, I made a mistake in the dataset, I updated it again, could you please check it again

Comment: For me, still printing nested lists. When I print the dataframe in my notebook, it shows some extra ids in the left (plz look at the question again)

Comment: I've updated the answer earlier. Did you try all 3 methods I've proposed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164326/discussion-between-laiho-b-and-allen).